# Deploying ASP.Net application to two Windows servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, synchronization

I've got this *Asp.Net MVC* App I would like to deploy to my two servers running *Windows Server 2012*. Actually I've got ***two servers*** on which I would like the application to run. Only one server is used at some point in time and the second is just a copy of the first. Both servers must be in the exactly **same state** at any time so that when one of them is broken, I could **redirect users** to the second without them noticing any change.

**Question:**
How to sync the application on both servers to avoid having different states from one server to the other?

Comment: [Setup Load Balancing IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815162), try this

Comment: Thanks a lot @MayankPathak. I read the topic, very instructive. Still it doesn't tell me exactly what to do. Should I deploy to each server separately? Which configuration files should I copy? They're talking about staging server, does it mean that I should have one more server to take care of request distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this ARR setup configuration in IIS
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Comment: I Read a lot about AAR but I still can't figure out if I should have three servers instead of two. In either case, should I deploy the app to one of them or all of them? Is there no sort of full tutorial to make my app work in this configuration?

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting the word "AAR" around, I made a lot of researches around it and I ended finding a whole youtube playlist about it. Text tutorials were not very explicit so this playlist helped me a lot. Here's the link: [Windows server 2012 High availability](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKWqPrqG4yyRA0zkDfD78V6_S51twERPX)